# Why Ubuntu Installation asks to disable Secure Boot?

Tags: system-installation, secure-boot

I installed Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty) on my Asus Laptop, Intel Core i7. When I was prompted for questions for the install such as disk partitions and other stuff, I was asked to disable Secure Boot if I wanted to get 3rd Party software for WiFi, graphics and sound. Now my question, should I disable it and comply, or leave it as enabled? Plus, what is secure boot and what will happen if I disable it? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't disable Secure Boot, you will be unable to install 3rd party kernel modules, like proprietary video or wireless drivers.

We don't know if you need any 3rd party kernel software or not.

You can keep it enabled if you don't need them. Another limitation will be that hibernation doesn't work in Ubuntu with enabled Secure Boot.

Secure Boot is a mechanism in UEFI that checks signatures of OS kernel and doesn't let to load unsigned OS's or modules.

Nothing terrible will happen if you disable it. It is not a very useful feature in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Basically secure boot may prevent you from loading some driver you installed which can be quite frustrating.

Personally I disagree with the seeming ubiquitous advice to turn off secure boot, works just fine on my hardware with secure boot enabled. IMO leave secure boot enabled unless you have a problem with it, no reason to blindly disable security features.